# partial specialization non type argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I need some help here. I'm new at meta programming so I don't even know where to look to find a solution (which so far I think is not even possible).

```
template<typename T, void(*FuncPtr_A)(int), int(*FuncPtr_B)() = nullptr>
class DummyClass
{ };

template<typename T, int(*FuncPtr_B)()>
class DummyClass<T, nullptr, FuncPtr_B>
{ };

void FUNC_A(int) { }
int FUNC_B() { return 0;  }

int main()
{
    DummyClass <int, FUNC_A, FUNC_B> test1;  // works
    DummyClass <int, FUNC_A> test2;          // works
    DummyClass <int, FUNC_B> test3;          // error: is there any way to make this work?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already know how to do that. I'm new at meta programming, not new at C++. I just want to know if something close to what I'm trying to do is possible, or at least confirm that it's not possible and there's no way around it.

Comment: Your specialization doesn't specialize btw, that you seems to want is a kind of alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could do was this:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, void(*FuncPtr_A)(int), int(*FuncPtr_B)()>
    class DummyClass
    { };
}

template<class T, void(*FuncPtr_A)(int)>
auto DummyClass()
{
    return detail::DummyClass<T, FuncPtr_A, nullptr>();
}

template<class T, int(*FuncPtr_B)(void)>
auto DummyClass()
{
    return detail::DummyClass<T, nullptr, FuncPtr_B>();
}

template<class T, void(*FuncPtr_A)(int), int(*FuncPtr_B)(void)>
auto DummyClass()
{
    return detail::DummyClass<T, FuncPtr_A, FuncPtr_B>();
}




void FUNC_A(int) { }
int FUNC_B() { return 0;  }

int main()
{
    auto test1 = DummyClass <int, FUNC_A, FUNC_B>();  // works
    auto test2 = DummyClass <int, FUNC_A> ();          // works
    auto test3 = DummyClass <int, FUNC_B> ();          // works
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

If you need to name the type (e.g. for using as a data member in a class):

```
int main()
{
    decltype(DummyClass <int, FUNC_A, FUNC_B>()) test1 {};   // works
    decltype(DummyClass <int, FUNC_A> ()) test2 {};          // works
    decltype(DummyClass <int, FUNC_B> ()) test3 {};          // works
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid C++11.

Comment: @jotik really? it compiles under apply clang with the -std=c++1z flag

Comment: @jotik: it is valid c++14, for c++11, you have to specify the type instead of `auto` return type.

Comment: who still uses c++11? The future is bright, walk into it! ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 oops. Didn't occur to me to check whether anyone was still using anything older than c++14. I mean, for new code, why would you? :P

Comment: @RichardHodges What did you think the `z` stands for in `-std=c++1z`?

Comment: @RichardHodges But I can't have the variables test1/test2/test3 as  class member variables with auto, since the c++11/14 class member initializer doesn't allow auto. I obviously don't want to write the full type myself. I have updated the tag to C+14. Sorry for wrong tag. This is what I mean: http://ideone.com/YBsiLG

Comment: Thanks for helping. Accepted this answer, altho I'm probably not going to use the decltype fix, it's too ugly.

Comment: @Phantom no problem dude. It was fun to think through the question. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in C++11 (nor C++14) using the syntax in the original question, because

1. you can only default template arguments at the **end** of the template parameter list, and
2. you can't have a non-type template parameter accept argument values of different types, unless they are convertible to the type of the non-type template parameter according to the conversion rules rules in C++11 §14.3.2.5.

Note that even if you pass an argument which is convertible in this manner, this does not help you specialize your template based on the original type of the argument.

Also note that 1. similarly holds for function default arguments, however for functions you can work around the issue by means of providing overloads based on the types of the arguments, which is the trick on which the factory pattern workaround proposed by skypjack's comment to the question and [RichardHodges answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36030400/3919155) relies upon.

Comment: I'm guessing that everything holds the same in C++14? I have updated my tag, sorry for having it wrong in the first place.